# Error al cargar rutas en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php5

```
Route::get('foo', function (){
    return 'Hello World';
  });
```

Este es el ejemplo de la pagina oficial de Laravel, pero al momento te hacerlo me sale:

> "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found."

Agradezco si me pueden ayudar en alguna cosa, ¡gracias!

Comment: Que url usas? Para acceder?

Comment: describe por favor el escenario de manera completa para comprender mejor donde pudiera estar el error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

creo que tienes que modificar la ruta a esta forma /foo

```
Route::get('/foo', function (){
  return 'Hello World';
});
```

Comment: el uso de la diagonal es totalmente opcional y no es impedimento para que la petición a la URL funcione